# Determine if a rails application is started with the `rails server` command?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having problems with these commands:

```
rails generate  
rails destroy  
rails console  
rake
```

I need to run long operations, only if an application is started via `rails server`.

`Rails.env.production?` is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the environments how you should be, then you'd limit your actions where you want to use this condition to the development or staging environments, regardless if you use rails server or not, right?

Most sites never use `rails server` in production and it sounds like you don't want it for your testing environment... so why not just use `if Rails.env.development?` (and staging if you have one).